# Remove Google Pin + Break New Line Marker Text in Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

[image]
what I want is to:

1. remove the red google pin
2. break the blue text into multiple lines just like what the info window look like

I have looked around and some answers are: use \n or 
 in title or content.
I have tried them but both didnt work.
the only thing work for me is label (but somehow it doesnt recognize \n or

I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boyboyjc/0gp101oL/19/) for simple code

Javascript

```
      // The following example creates a marker label in Gillete Stadium 
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.4914,132.5510);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: latLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          draggable: true,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: latLng,
          //title: 'Line 1<br/>Line2\nLine3',   //doesnt work   
          //content: 'Line 1<br/>Line2\nLine3', //doesnt work
        label: {
          color: 'black',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: '32px',
          text: 'Line 1<br/>Line2\nLine3',
        },
      });
```

HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="download-map"></div>
```

CSS

```
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 90%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Add the code to the question please

Comment: The documentation states that a label is a single charachter that appears on the marker - though it appears to accept more than one character but is simple text. Why not use an infowindow? or create your own window with the content you want?

Comment: @RamRaider thank you for the reply.. the code is there, in the jsfiddle. Im not allowed to display links.. infowindow is the last resort.. why we chose it for the last resort is because to show infowindow you need to hover/click your mouse to the pin.. and I want to remove the red google pin..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand - you can open infowindows without any markers, so perhaps this might help?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: Infowindow with no marker</title>
        <script async defer src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<API-KEY>&callback=initMap&region=en-GB&language=en"></script>
        <script>
            var map;


            function initMap(){
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    maxWidth:100
                });
                var centre=new google.maps.LatLng( 55.959553, -3.178480 );


                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: centre,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    disableDefaultUI: true
                } );


                infoWindow.setContent( "an infoWindow, centred on Edinburgh for no apparent reason, with no markers anywhere to be seen." );
                infoWindow.setPosition( centre );
                infoWindow.open( map, null );
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            body{ background:white;padding:0;margin:0; }

            #map {
                width: 100%;
                height:100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                clear:none;
                display:block;
                background:white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes if we are using info window, using your code we can remove the pin. but if you look at my jsfiddle, Im not using info window at all.. thanks for coming back here anyway.